# Create persistent Ubuntu on USB with more than 4GB of space (Ubuntu 16.04.1)

Tags: live-usb, persistence

Following instructions of deleting casper-rw and creating a second ext2/ext4 partition labeled casper-rw makes USB pen-drive crash.

Tried all combinations I have fond. All results in:

```
BusyBox .... built-in shell...
(initramfs)
```

And it stops here.

What to do? I am on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: I used the installer to properly install Ubuntu 16.04.1 to the USB drive instead. Seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The tool ***mkusb*** can create USB pendrives with persistent live Ubuntu systems. It creates a **casper-rw partition** for persistence automatically.

You can decide how much of the available drive space to use for persistence. The rest (of the available drive space) will be used for a **usbdata** partition, available also from Windows.

See these links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)